# Why rotating imageView, it changes position?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, frame, nslog

when I use: ImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(ImageView.transform, rotation); everytime I rotate imageView and I NSLog(@"x:%f y:%f", ImageView.frame.orgin.x, ImageView.frame.orgin.y), x and y always change value?? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Well the `.frame.origin` is the top left corner of you `UIImageView` and since you are rotating it the top left corner is moving. If you access the `.center` it should stay the same.

Comment: when I move view using: CGAffineTransformTranslate(view.transform, difx, dify); And I get: view.center.x, this value not changes when I move it??

Comment: @HuỳnhPhong Center changes when you move the view. By setting the translation transform you are just displaying the content with offset to the position of the view. Translation _does not_ move the view.

Comment: Thanks! How to I get center point current when I move view using CGAffineTransformTranslate ?

Comment: To get the translation: `view.transform.tx` and `view.transform.ty`. These coordinates are relative to view's `center`, so to get absolute X: `view.center.x + view.transform.tx`.

Answer (score 0):

The UIView [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) states that

> Warning: If this property is not the identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

regarding the transform property of a UIView. Since you are assigning to the transform it is most likely not the identity transform any more, hence the frame value is undefined, and should be ignored.

Comment: This is strange, because for me `frame` always worked as bounding box of the rotated view.

Comment: I agree it sounds strange, and I have also used the frame property as "the way the superview sees it", and then the bounds gives the actual rotated view coordinates. I saw this documentation for the first time today.