# Why does a view changes position when rotating it using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I have the following super simple animation, I'm basically rotating a view 2 radians from its original angle/center, it rotates fine my only misunderstanding is why does the view move from its original position when the rotation occurs.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.someView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 2 );
    }];
```

Why does the view moves when rotated with the code above?

[image]

I'm currently trying to discern the information in the [CGAffineTransform Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation).

Understanding the anchor [point](http://ideveloper.co/understanding-the-anchor-point/).

I found this threads but it doesn't show a concrete answer.
[Why rotating imageView, it changes position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786908/why-rotating-imageview-it-changes-position)

Thanks a lot

Comment: It should rotate about the view's center unless you've changed the anchor point of the view's layer. Could you describe the position change or perhaps post images showing how the view has changed position?

Comment: I haven't moved the anchor point, in fact the code above is the only code I have in an action/method which is trigger when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am adding another answer due to @fs_tigre request. The problem is with the auto layouts in your xib file, unfortunately is it unknown why that affects the transform.  
Now here is the steps I did to solve the issue:

1- first you need to get rid off your auto layout (yes, you have to)
**uncheck Use Autolayout** 
[image: uncheck Use Autolayout]

2- remove all constraints and autoresizing masks for your view that will be rotated, as in the screenshot
**(Here I have my blue box, see on the right autoresizing, nothing is selected)** 
[image]

I have made some changes for your rotation's code

```
self.someView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    // one degree = pi/180. so...
    // rotate by 90
    CGFloat radians = (M_PI/180) * 90;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.someView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.someView.transform, radians);
    }];
```

Click `rotate` and see the magic :)

Comment: @fs_tigre here is a video for you https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wxar56o4jbyrdg/video.mov

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time and actually tried it out. That answers my question. I guess if you want to transform views and want to use atutolayout you would have to use a subviews, as described in the third suggestion of the post by Matt Neuburg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used/14105757#14105757

Comment: @fs_tigre, I haven't tried that, but I think its a good solution tho. But When I deal with a lot of animations I like to disable auto layouts, to avoid their headache

Comment: why CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5) ? how to get it dynamic

Answer (score 10):

You need to set the anchor point of your view to rotate around.

```
self.somview.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
```

Then start the rotation. 
From Apple documentations

> `@property(nonatomic) CGAffineTransform transform` 
>  Changes to this
>   property can be animated. Use the beginAnimations:context: class
>   method to begin and the commitAnimations class method to end an
>   animation block. The default is whatever the center value is (or
>   anchor point if changed)
>   Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint

[image] 
image from here http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit 
- As you see the anchor point is the point with the value from 0.0 - 1.0 for X and Y
when you rotate the rotation will be around these points 
NOTE: you need to import QuartzCore

Comment: I still don't know understand this, setting the anchor point didn't make a difference, still moving its position. The funny thing is that if I change the rotation to 3.14 radians(180degrees) or 6.28 radians (360degress) it works fine without even setting the anchor point.    `- (IBAction)rotateIt:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14);
        self.view2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(6.28);
    }];
}
@end ` This code works fine. Why it only works with 3.14 and 6.28 radians?

Comment: It seems to be at the default 0.5, 0.5 because if I change it to something else like, `self.somview.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.7, 0.7);` it actually responds to those new values but if I set it to `self.somview.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);` it doesn't make a difference, it just behaves as if nothings has been set. (See the image I posted in my original post).

Comment: I'm wondering if this has to do with Autolayout. Eventhow I didn't apply any constraints to the view I'm trying to rotate it may be affected by the fact that autolayout is set by default in any new project you create in Xcode 5." I found this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used" that talks about autolayout impacting transformations.

Comment: if you confirm that the auto layout is disabled for this view, then I will try to test it on my side and comeback to you.

Comment: Thank you Basheer_CAD, unfortunately I cannot confirm this at the moment since I'm away from my desk but I will do it as soon as I get home. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 3):

The "anchor" of `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` is the X,Y of the view. You can try this:

```
CGPoint center = self.someView.center;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.someView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 2 );
    self.someView.center = center;
}];
```

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I tried this code but it didn't work either, it still moves the view before it starts rotating. But it works if I change the rotation angle to 3.14 radians or 6.28 radians.